# How to add a 404 for a specific URL in htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have a page at http://www.example.com/my-inner-page. I need my server to respond with a 404 when someone tries to access this url. What is the rule I would use in htaccess to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason you want to do this with htaccess and not by simply removing the file?

Comment: It's a Wordpress site. If I change the permalink, Wordpress will 301 to the updated url. This particular URL is getting hit hard by spam backlinks. I need to 404 it so these backlinks stop penalizing my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch 404 "my-inner-page"
```